# Yii2 render xml for sitemap

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm trying to create a sitemap for my web so I create an action to render a sitemap in format xml but i get a plain text file

My action :

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $channels = Channel::find()->all(); 

        $response = Yii::$app->response;
        $response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_XML;

        $headers = Yii::$app->response->headers;
        $headers->add('Content-Type', 'application/xml');

        return $this->renderPartial('/sitemap/_viewChannel', [
            'channels'   => $channels,
        ]);
    }
```

My view :

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">

    <?php foreach ($channels as $channel){ ?>
        <url>
            <loc><?=Url::to(['/chn-channel/view', 't'=>$channel->channel_uid])?></loc>
            <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        </url>
    <?php } ?>

</urlset>
```

but I get a normal plain text as output

Output : 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're missing XML declaration at the beginning of your XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

But XML *is* a plain text, it just uses specified markup and rules - the way how browser formats this output is in fact irrelevant. You need to use some sitemap validator (for example https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/validate-xml-sitemap.html or https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/sitemap-list) to check if there are any issues with your sitemap.

Comment: in google sitemap We encountered an error while trying to access your Sitemap. Please ensure your Sitemap follows our guidelines and can be accessed at the location you provided and then resubmit.  URL restricted by robots.txt

Answer (score 1):

Find solution by changing :

```
$response = Yii::$app->response;
$response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_XML;

$headers = Yii::$app->response->headers;
$headers->add('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
```

to

```
Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_RAW;
Yii::$app->response->headers->add('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
```